# Class instantiation from string

Tags: actionscript-3

Is it possible to have a string "ClassA" and use it in order to instantiate a real ClassA in my application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at flash.utils.getDefinitionByName.  You should be able to use that to get a class object from a string of the class name.

Comment: note that this has to be a fully qualified name, so if your class is defined in `com.namespace.subspace.MyClass`, you should have `var MyClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("com.namespace.subspace::MyClass") as Class; var myObj = new MyClass();`

Comment: @Ponty - yes, it should work with any class - as @Ender noted, it must be fully qualified with appropriate package(s).

Comment: I have a png image on Library that i have declared it via Properties as Background class which extends BitmapData. When i type: var BMDClass:Class = getDefinitionByName( "Background" ) as Class; i get: variable Background is not defined!!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [getDefinitionByName](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName()) in the `flash.utils` package

```
var ClassReference:Class = getDefinitionByName("ClassA") as Class;
```

You will need the full path to the name so for example say `mypackage.stuff.ClassA` the call would like

```
var ClassReference:Class = getDefinitionByName("mypackage.stuff.ClassA") as Class;
var instance:Object = new ClassReference();
```

Then use can use `instance` to do your methods

```
instance.methodname();
```

Remember if you want to add it to the Display List you will have to cast it as a `DisplayObject`

```
addChild(DisplayObject(instance));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Eval("new "+myString+"()");
```

or possibly even

```
new Eval(myString)();
```

but I'm not sure Actionscript will support the second one.

Comment: Yeah, eval was removed in AS3

Answer (score 0):

Now i can  instantiate the image form libary by string ,this is my code!

```
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
var ClassReference:Class = getDefinitionByName("my0002") as Class;
var instance:BitmapData = new ClassReference();
var myb:Bitmap =new Bitmap (instance)
this.addChild (myb)
```